# SQL Server 2012 output to txt file is adding spaces to end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a project to output a query to .txt from SQL Server 2012 where the data type is `varchar(25)` and the string length is variable. The output is adding spaces to the end of the string to make the output equal to the column width. I have tried `rtrim()` however the spaces do not exist in the source data. I cannot change the column data type.

Data example is 'XXXXX.XXX' and output looks like this 'XXXXX.XXX                '

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Please share us a code that you have already wrote to achieve the result. Anyway follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know more about how to ask a good question

Comment: Yep. You're right `rtim()` doesn't work, because it doesn't exist. You've also not shown us how you're exporting, so it's pretty difficult to explain why it might not work as expected.

Comment: SQL Server does not proactively add spaces, save for when converting to fixed length types (`CHAR(25)`). You'll need to add more detail on how you're producing that `.txt` file. What language, framework, package, what have you?